# Is there a cleaner/elegant way than creating closure to access outer function from inner?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code.. ala

```
$.fn.someObj= function(){
    this.opt = {
       whatever : 'somevalue',
       whateve2 : 'more values'
    }
    this.someMethod = function(){
       //do something
       $(someElem).bind('click',function(){
          this.someOTHERMethod();  <----- ISSUE HERE
       })
    }
    this.someOTHERMethod = function(){
       // do more stuff

    }
   this.init = function(data){
       $.extend(this.opt, data);
       this.someMethod();
 };

};
```

I can create a closure and fix the issue;

```
var that = this;
    //code
    that.someOTHERMethod(); <--- works
```

or if I remove the "this" from the method:

```
someOTHERMethod = function(){}

and just call it: someOTHERMethod(); < ---- works
```

But I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to get that outer func without a closure or ? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a closure, you can just pass a reference to your function, and eliminate the wrapper anonymous function:

```
$(someElem).on('click', this.someOTHERMethod);
```

If you want the `this` value inside `someOTHERMethod` to be `someObj`, then use `$.proxy` too, as per zzzzBov's answer.

Comment: actually, this doesn't work either. not sure if its the "on" - I only have access to jQuery 1.6. Is ".bind" creating the closure? When do what you have here and just use ".bind" instead of ".on" it doesn't work. strange. if I use "this.someOTHERMethdo" - the method is never reached.. if I use "()" - I get a this. is undefined.

Comment: On jQuery 1.6 you have to use `bind` instead of `on` (which was introduced only in 1.7); or `$(someElem).click` directly. Now I noticed your code looks like a jQuery plugin. If so, you shouldn't be using `this` like that (or it will refer to the global object, `window`).

Comment: In a jQuery plugin, you should *at least* `return this` at the end. Then you'd be able to use it like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGrqc, which is actually unusual. See the [Plugin Authoring Guidelines](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: Thank you Bfavaretto - appreciate your concise posts. I realized I was trying to "force" a plugin approach to a non-plugin need. I ended up creating a constructor with some prototypes, and then just create 'new', and it all seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using jQuery, you should use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy)

```
$(someElem).on('click', $.proxy(this, 'someOTHERMethod'));
```

Comment: just wondering, isn't that a little overkill? I think declaring the `someOTHerMethod()` function as a variable inside `$.fn.someObj` would work better...

Comment: `$.proxy` may or may not be necessary, depending on what's inside `someOTHERMethod`. The issue here seems to be a superfluous anonymous function creating an unnecessary new scope.